# Would it be sensible to add number of years to the skill sets, as every agents asks?

Tags: resume

In context of contracts, I get call by agents every now and then, they usually always ask for number of years I had been working with a technology.

On my CV I am listing skills as text only.

Would it be a clever move to add duration working with a skill as well ? Any side effects ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it would.

It would save people asking you for that information.

Generally speaking, if you get repeated queries for certain information, it makes sense to include that information in your CV/resume.

Comment: I would also break them down into _Core/Key Skills_ and _Other Skills_. My CV (Contractor 20+ years; Permie 12 years) has this as a table on page 1, right after my contact details.